# Condizionale o congiuntivo?

Tags: verbs, grammar, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

1. Penso che sia/sarebbe meglio questo.
2. Pensavo che fosse/sarebbe stato meglio questo.

Il dubbio mi viene perché i verbi che reggono l'indicativo, reggono  anche il condizionale:

- Dico che è meglio/sarebbe meglio questo.
- Dicevo che sarebbe meglio questo.

Secondo voi, mi faccio condizionare dal fatto che "o si usa il condizionale o il congiuntivo" oppure entrambe le costruzioni sono equivalenti o utilizzabili?

Comment: Così a orecchio, direi che il congiuntivo denoti un'opinione più forte rispetto al condizionale.

Comment: D'accordo con egreg: "Penso che sarebbe meglio questo" è dubitativo. Ma a me pare che questa sfumatura dubitativa sfumi un po', o scompaia, nelle forme al passato.

Answer (score 2):

Si usa il condizionale "sarei" per qualcosa che non si verifica.

"Penso che tu sia più bella bionda" significa: tu sei bionda, e per questo sei più bella. Oppure, tu a volte sei bionda e a volte non lo sei, ma io preferisco quando lo sei.

"Penso che tu saresti più bella bionda" significa: tu NON sei bionda, e penso che se tu lo fossi saresti più bella.

Answer (score 0):

Sono entrambe utilizzabili ma con scopi diversi.

Se uso il congiuntivo e dico

> penso che sia meglio fare così

sto esprimento una mia opinione nel presente e mi riferisco a un qualcosa di sempre vero per me ora.

Se dico invece

> penso che sarebbe meglio fare così

sto dicendo che secondo me, in futuro, se mai qualcuno farà qualcosa a riguardo, sarà meglio fare così. La mia opinione rimane, ma si riferisce a una *condizione* che deve essere ancora soddisfatta.

Il congiuntivo ha un'accezione più netta, il condizionale esprime un'opinione di cui non si è certi. Il condizionale in generale è il tempo dell'incertezza proprio perchè specifica un qualcosa che accadrebbe solo e soltanto in una determinata condizione. Il periodo ipotetico (escluso il primo ovviamente) ne è un esempio lampante:

> Se mia nonna avesse le ruote, sarebbe una carriola.

Se la condizione ben definita (guarda un po'  col congiuntivo) si verificasse, allora succederebbe che...

Perché ho escluso il periodo ipotetico della realtà? Perché non usa il condizionale. E perché non usa il condizionale? Perché rappresenta qualcosa di certo, reale o molto probabile.

> Se l'acqua raggiunge zero gradi, si solidifica.

Comment: non capisco cosa ci sia di sbagliato nella risposta. Se mi date un feedback vedo cosa posso fare per correggerla o eliminarla (se inappropriata)

Comment: Non sono io che ha dato il -1 ma sospetto che sia per l’esempio della nonna, non esattamente di buon gusto e potenzialmente offensivo. Se fossi in te lo cambierei visto che le possibilità sono infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Vanno bene entrambe, dipende anche dal contesto, se intendo esprimere cortesemente un mio convincimento o una mia volontà (1) oppure dare un suggerimento (2):
1a. Penso che sia più adatto Luigi (sono io che comando)
1b. Penso che sia meglio fermarci (sto guidando io)
2a. Penso che Luigi sarebbe più adatto
2b. Penso che sarebbe meglio fermarci.